# Angular OOP services and caching

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, angular.js, cache, factory-method

I've created a caching service using OOP techniques combined with the revealing module pattern and the [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) library. New `CacheDataClass` objects are instantiated using the Factory pattern with `RequestFactory`. It has generic methods for get, set and reset data. It can be extended to override those methods. I would be very grateful if this can be reviewed and for any suggestions for improvement.

The factory itself:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('dataservices')
    .factory('CacheDataClass', CacheDataClass);

    CacheDataClass.$inject = ['CacheFactory'];

    function CacheDataClass(CacheFactory) {

        var CacheData = function(uid) {
            this.uid = uid;
            this.newData = null;
            this.cache = this.initCache();
        };

        CacheData.prototype = {
            constructor: CacheData,
            initCache: function() {
                var self = this;

                if (!CacheFactory.get(self.uid + '/cache')) {
                    CacheFactory.createCache(self.uid + '/cache', {
                        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive'
                    });
                }
                var cache = CacheFactory.get(self.uid + '/cache');

                self.cache = cache;
                return cache;
            },
            getData: function() {
                var self = this;

                self.newData = self.cache.get(self.uid) ?
                    self.cache.get(self.uid) :
                    {};

                return self.newData;
            },
            setData: function(data) {
                var self = this;
                var cache = self.initCache(); 

                cache.put(self.uid, data);
                self.cache = cache;
            },
            resetData: function() {
                var self = this;

                self.cache.remove(self.uid);
                self.newData = {};
                return self.newData;
            }
        };

        return CacheData;

    }
})();
```

Request factory:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('dataservices')
    .factory('RequestFactory', RequestFactory);

    RequestFactory.$inject = ['CacheDataClass']; 

    function RequestFactory(CacheDataClass) {
        return {
            createCache: function(uid) {
                return new CacheDataClass(uid);
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Example implementation:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('cacheExample')
    .controller('CacheExampleController', CacheExampleController);

    CacheExampleController.$inject = ['CacheFactory', 'RequestFactory', '$stateParams']; 

    function CacheExampleController(CacheFactory, RequestFactory, $stateParams) {
        var vm = this;

        activate();

        function activate() {
            vm.paramsCache = RequestFactory.createCache($location.path() + userID);
        }

        function setCache() {
            vm.paramsCache.setData({
                userID: $stateParams.userID,
                email: $stateParams.email,
            });
        }
    }
})();
```